# Understanding the input format of eval in python

Tags: python, eval

```
str = "a b c"
eval(str) # throws error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 1
a b c
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but

```
str = "\'a b c\'"
eval(str) # prints
'a b a'
```

What is the difference between the 2 conditions. Why is the character ' required.  ?

Comment: Try typing `a b c` in a Python shell. Then try `'a b c'`.

Comment: One is a string literal (the one that works) the other is a syntax error... what is it that you don't get exactly? What do you think `eval` does?

Comment: Note, also, `eval( "'a b c'") ` is totally silly. Just use `"'a b c'"`

Comment: Also, there are *no lists anywhere in your code*. What do you mean by *list*?

Answer (score 0):

`eval("a = 5")` executes the contents of the string as python code.  For example, after executing `eval("a = 5")`, variable `a` would hold the value `5`.

As for why `eval("a b c")` throws an error and `eval("'a b c'")` does not, the usual convention for method/class documentation in Python is to use a multi-line string.  As such, strings are valid statements in python.  Note that you should still use `#` for single-line comments.

```
def method_a(str):
    """
    This method does blah blah blah.
    input:
        <str> str   The string to be processed
    """
    if str is None:
        # avoid null errors.
        return ""
    else:
        return str
```